# SKLearn Perceptron behaving differently for sparse and dense

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, perceptron

Perceptron, when given the matrix in dense format, gives different results as compared to giving the same matrix in sparse format. I thought it could be a shuffling issue, so I ran Cross Validation using `cross_validate` from `sklearn.model_selection` but no luck.

A similar issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660771/different-results-when-using-sklearn-randomizedpca-with-sparse-and-dense-matrice). But there is some rationale given. Is there any rationale here?

FYI, the parameters I am using Perceptron with are:
`penalty='l2', alpha=0.0001, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=10000, tol=1e-8, shuffle=True, verbose=0, eta0=1.0, n_jobs=1, random_state=0, class_weight=None, warm_start=False, n_iter=None`

I am using `sparse.csr_matrix` to convert the dense to sparse matrix as accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922487/how-to-transform-numpy-matrix-or-array-to-scipy-sparse-matrix)

Comment: Please show some reproducible example.

Comment: @sascha, Sorry for the miss. But u can refer to the accepted answer's example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a rationale here.**

`Perceptron` [shares](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron) most of the code with `SGDClassifier`

> Perceptron and SGDClassifier share the same underlying implementation. In fact, Perceptron() is equivalent to SGDClassifier(loss=”perceptron”, eta0=1, learning_rate=”constant”, penalty=None).

and `SGDClassifier` is [better documented](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#stochastic-gradient-descent-for-sparse-data):

> Note: The sparse implementation produces slightly different results than the dense implementation due to a shrunk learning rate for the intercept.

we have more details [latter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#implementation-details):

> In the case of sparse feature vectors, the intercept is updated with a smaller learning rate (multiplied by 0.01) to account for the fact that it is updated more frequently.

Note that this implementation details comes from [Leon Bottou](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/sgd):

> The learning rate for the bias is multiplied by 0.01 because this frequently improves the condition number.

For completeness, in [scikit-learn code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ac1b04875331fc291a437025a18ddfefd4051d7c/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L43-L45):

```py
SPARSE_INTERCEPT_DECAY = 0.01
# For sparse data intercept updates are scaled by this decay factor to avoid
# intercept oscillation.
```

Bonus example:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

np.random.seed(42)
n_samples, n_features = 1000, 10
X_dense = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
X_csr = sp.csr_matrix(X_dense)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=n_samples)

for X in [X_dense, X_csr]:
    model = Perceptron(penalty='l2', alpha=0.0001, fit_intercept=True,
                       max_iter=10000, tol=1e-8, shuffle=True, verbose=0,
                       eta0=1.0, n_jobs=1, random_state=0, class_weight=None,
                       warm_start=False, n_iter=None)
    model.fit(X, y)
    print(model.coef_)
```

You can check that the coefficients are different.
Changing `fit_intercept` to `False` makes the coefficients equal, yet the fit may be poorer.

Comment: So, ideally speaking, if I change the delay to 1, they should perform the same but I might face problems as mentioned (intercept oscillation). Right? @TomDLT

Comment: Right. But if your data is not sparse (even though the object is a CSR matrix), you won't have problems. Reversely, if your data is very sparse but stored in a dense object, you might face intercept oscillations problems.